# How does Chrome "Simplify Page"?

Tags: python, google-chrome, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm trying to implement this in Python and don't know where to start. My ultimate goal is to extract the title and body from news article such as:

http://investorplace.com/2016/08/csco-stock-2-trades-cisco-systems-earnings/

Comment: Have you looked at the bs4 or the scrapy docs ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `webpage source` and use `inspect element` in the items that you want!

Then it's all a matter of creating a `soup()` and using `find()` or `findAll()` to retrieve the correct tags.